# Creating and writing files with php

Tags: php, file-io

Is it possible to pass a variable to 'file_get_contents' in php? Am getting errors and wondered if it was my syntax. Am using the code below.

```
$page=file_get_contents('http://localhost/home/form.php?id={$data['form_id']}');
$fp=fopen('form.html','w+');
fputs($fp,$page);
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: what are you trying to do with such a code? there is no sense in requesting your own file via HTTP.

Answer (score 6):

To use this syntax, use `"` quotes instead of `'` ones.

`$page=file_get_contents("http://localhost/home/form.php?id={$data['form_id']}");`

or

`$page=file_get_contents('http://localhost/home/form.php?id='.$data['form_id']);`

Answer (score 2):

I prefer to use just one method for writing and reading a file, for example this 2 combination:

---

**Combination one**

Writing: `file_put_contents`

Reading: `file_get_contents`

---

**Combination two**

Writing: `fwrite`

Reading: `fread`

---

In my opinion that's a little more consistent.