# Creating editing and writing files

Tags: php, string, file-io

Im trying to use file_get_contents to get contents of a file and delete a certain part of a line in that file.

Is the following anywhere near what I want to achieve?

```
 $page = file_get_contents('myPage.php?id='.$_GET['id']);
 $file = 'temp/form_'.$_GET['id'].'.html';
 $change = file_get_contents('myPage.php?id='.$_GET['id']);
 $change = str_replace("/Elements/", "", $change);
 file_put_contents($page, $file);
```

Comment: Possibly dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434210/creating-and-writing-files-with-php

Comment: What do your trials indicate? Is it doing what you expect it to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$page = file_get_contents('myPage.php?id='.$_GET['id']);
```

This gets the contents of the file `myPage.php?id=...` *in the current directory*. Since this looks like a part of an URL, you probably want to retrieve some webpage with this statement. If that is the case, you need to use the full URL.

```
$change = file_get_contents('myPage.php?id='.$_GET['id']);
```

This again gets the same file as in line 1. You could use `$page` instead of `$change` and leave this line out, like this:

```
$change = str_replace("/Elements/", "", $page);
```

The function `file_put_contents` has the filename as first parameter, and the data as second parameter. You have it the other way around.